# Error handling in WebFlux with RouterFunction

Tags: spring-webflux

I am having trouble making my reactive code handle errors in a common way. The ideal way would be in a reusable component that I can add as a dependency in other projects.

In the past, we used `@RestControllerAdvise` to handle them with personalized `@ExceptionHandler` functions. For reference, my code:

```
@Configuration
public class VesselRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(VesselHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/vessels/{imoNumber}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::getVesselByImo)
                .andRoute(GET("/vessels").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::getVessels);
    }
}
```

Also, the handler class:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VesselHandler {
    private VesselsService vesselsService;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getVesselByImo(ServerRequest request) {
        String imoNumber = request.pathVariable("imoNumber");
        Mono<VesselResponse> response = this.vesselsService.getByImoNumber(imoNumber);
        return response.hasElement().flatMap(vessel -> {
                if (vessel) {
                    return ServerResponse.ok()
                            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .body(response, VesselResponse.class);
                } else {
                    throw new DataNotFoundException("The data you seek is not here.");
                }
            }
        );

    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getVessels(ServerRequest request) {
        return this.vesselsService.getAllVessels();
    }
}
/**
 * Exception class to be thrown when data not found for the requested resource
 */
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public DataNotFoundException(String e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

And in our common library:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes={VesselHandler.class})
// FIXME: referencing class here is not good, it will create circular dependency when moved to it's own jar
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionHandlers {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = DataNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleDataNotFoundException(DataNotFoundException dataNotFoundException,
                                                                ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest) {
        //habdling expcetions code here
    }
}
```

Also with the exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionHandlers {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = DataNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleDataNotFoundException(DataNotFoundException dataNotFoundException,
                                                                ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest) {
        //habdling expcetions code here
    }
}
```

I have read in the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-controller-advice), that this is the way it should work, but my unit test doesn't seem to be going anywhere near the exception handler:

```
@Test
    public void findByImoNoData() {
        when(vesselsService.getByImoNumber("1234567")).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        webTestClient.get().uri("/vessels/1234567")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isNotFound();
    }
```

I have also tried to use the `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler` as with the example in [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors). Doesn't seem to work either:

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    public GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ResourceProperties resourceProperties, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(errorAttributes, resourceProperties, applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(
            ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {

        return RouterFunctions.route(
                RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(
            ServerRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, false);

        return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(errorPropertiesMap));
    }
}
```

So, how do you do global error handling with WebFlux, without using `@RestController`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@ControllerAdvice` is only intended for the annotated programming model. To provide functionality like `ControllerAdvice` with functional endpoints you can leverage a [HandlerFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-handler-filter-function). From the reference:

> Routes mapped by a router function can be filtered by calling RouterFunction.filter(HandlerFilterFunction), where HandlerFilterFunction is essentially a function that takes a ServerRequest and HandlerFunction, and returns a ServerResponse. The handler function parameter represents the next element in the chain: this is typically the HandlerFunction that is routed to, but can also be another FilterFunction if multiple filters are applied. With annotations, similar functionality can be achieved using @ControllerAdvice and/or a ServletFilter.

```java
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
    return RouterFunctions
            .route(GET("/foo"), request -> Mono.error(new DataNotFoundException()))
            .andRoute(GET("/bar"), request -> Mono.error(new DataNotFoundException()))
            .filter(dataNotFoundToBadRequest());
}

private HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> dataNotFoundToBadRequest() {
    return (request, next) -> next.handle(request)
            .onErrorResume(DataNotFoundException.class, e -> ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a WebFilter to accomplish the same thing:

```java
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
    return RouterFunctions
            .route(GET("/foo"), request -> Mono.error(new DataNotFoundException()))
            .andRoute(GET("/bar"), request -> Mono.error(new DataNotFoundException()));
}

@Bean
WebFilter dataNotFoundToBadRequest() {
    return (exchange, next) -> next.filter(exchange)
            .onErrorResume(DataNotFoundException.class, e -> {
                ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                return response.setComplete();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I make up an AppException and throw it anywhere in the app (Rest controllers) where I think it should be an "error" response.

- AppException: my specific exception, it can contains anything you want to handle, display, return the error.

  ```
  public class AppException extends RuntimeException {
      int code;
      HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
      ...
  }
  ```

Then I define (a) global ControllerAdvice which take responsibility filtering out those AppExceptions.

Here is my sample, I can take out the AppException that I throw in the Rest Controller, then return it as a ReponseEntity with body as a "ErrorResponse" POJO.

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    boolean error = true;
    int code;
    String message;
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(AppException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleAppException(AppException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ErrorResponse(ex.getCode(), ex.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

In webflux, the error could be thrown by return Mono.error() as Rob Winch's answer.