# How to handle exceptions in spring-webflux based REST service

Tags: exception, spring-webflux

I'm building a REST service using spring-webflux. I need to respond with a custom json error response when the requested path is not found, or when any other internal server error happens.

I have a `GeneralExceptionHandler` class that implements `ErrorWebExceptionHandler`.

And I have a bean for the `GeneralExceptionHandler` as follows.

```
@Bean
@Order(-2)
public ErrorWebExceptionHandler errorWebExceptionHandler() {
    return new GeneralExceptionHandler();
}
```

This way my handle method (`public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, Throwable throwable)`) in `GeneralExceptionHandler`is called in case of errors like requested path not found.

And I'm able to use the following to send a custom http status code also.

`serverWebExchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);`

But I'm not able figure out how to send a custom JSON as response.

First of all is this the right way to handle general errors in Spring webflux? If yes, how can I respond with custom JSON objects?

Comment: are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: There are many ways for error handling in both Spring MVC and Spring Webflux.
I had an answer where I use a Global Controller Advice for handling app errors and return custom response.

You can check my answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961548/2145213.

Comment: @BrianClozel yes

Comment: @nghiaht your answer helps with app errors, but its not working with 404 and 405 errors.

Comment: @Thomas In my sample, I handle all errors by return HTTP 200 response, with error code and message.
But you could return any HTTP status, for example I return 401 Unauthorize

`return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(new ErrorResponse(ex.getCode(), ex.getMessage()));`

Use whatever HttpStatus that you want, you can set the status into exception before throwing it and use it in ControllerAdvice.

Answer (score 6):

Spring Boot provides that `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` interface for that purpose; it extends the rather general, low level `WebExceptionHandler` from Spring Framework.

With `WebExceptionHandler`, you're indeed stuck dealing with low level concepts, because it is meant as a general error handling mechanism.

There are several ways to customize the error handling process in Spring Boot:

- Create your own `ErrorAttributes` bean and add/remove data from the error map that's given to the HTML views or rendered as JSON
- If you'd like to deal even more with error processing, you can extend `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler`, which gives you all the building blocks to render HTML/response bodies
- If you want full control, you can implement a `ErrorWebExceptionHandler`, but you'll have to have similar infrastructure setup for rendering high level concepts such as views or serializing response bodies