# Can't catch an exception thrown from a reactive chain involving a RouterFunction

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I can't catch an exception thrown by a reactive operator (at least, not in a concise way)

```java
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> logInRoute() {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .POST("/login", tokenHandler::logIn)
                .onError(BadCredentialsException.class,
                        (t,r) -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).bodyValue(t.getMessage()))
                .build();
    }
```

```java
    public Mono<ServerResponse> logIn(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(UserDto.class) // Mono<UserDto>
                .map(this::toUnauthenticatedUpat) // Mono<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken>
                .flatMap(authenticationManager::authenticate) // it throws
                .map(tokenService::generateTokenFor) // Mono<String>
                .transform(jwt -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(jwt, String.class)) // Mono<ServerResponse>
                .onErrorResume(t ->
                        ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).bodyValue(t.getMessage()));
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken toUnauthenticatedUpat(UserDto userDto) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(
                userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getPassword());
    }
```

As you see, I put an error handling lambda both in the handler and in the function itself. None of them worked

```
ERROR 13444 --- [token-service] [oundedElastic-1] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [70d874e3-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/login"

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Invalid Credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:102) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$1592/0x00000008016608a0@433e5f3 [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/login" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

To be clear, the problem is *not the exception itself* (I send bad credentials on purpose), but the fact that I have trouble catching it and mapping to a 401 response. 500 is very misleading

The exception is thrown from `org.springframework.security.authentication.UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager`, specifically from the `authenticate()` it inherits from its abstract parent

```java
    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String presentedPassword = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        // @formatter:off
        return retrieveUser(username)
                .doOnNext(this.preAuthenticationChecks::check)
                .publishOn(this.scheduler)
                .filter((userDetails) -> this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword()))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Credentials"))))
                .flatMap((userDetails) -> upgradeEncodingIfNecessary(userDetails, presentedPassword))
                .doOnNext(this.postAuthenticationChecks::check)
                .map(this::createUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

A chat bot suggested this abomination, but it doesn't work too

```java
                .map(this::toUnauthenticatedUpat)
                .flatMap(user -> {
                    try {
                        return authenticationManager.authenticate(user);
                    } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
                        return Mono.error(ex);
                    }
                })
```

I also took [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936830/23434786) and tried chaining a filter:

```java
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> logInRoute() {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .POST("/login", tokenHandler::logIn)
                .filter((request, next) -> next.handle(request)
                        .onErrorResume(BadCredentialsException.class,
                                t -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).bodyValue(t.getMessage())))
                .build();
    }
```

Again, no effect

Of all the things I tried, only this ugly `WebFilter` works

```java
    @Bean
    public WebFilter badCredentialsToBadRequest() {
        return (exchange, next) -> next.filter(exchange)
                .onErrorResume(BadCredentialsException.class, e -> {
                    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    DefaultDataBufferFactory defaultDataBufferFactory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
                    DataBuffer dataBuffer = defaultDataBufferFactory.wrap(e.getMessage().getBytes());
                    return response.writeWith(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> dataBuffer));
                });
    }
```

So what is my mistake and how do I catch the exception properly¹?

¹ *that is, concisely, without a ton of code and all that low-level "buffer-whatever" stuff that I'm sure is too much for such a trivial task*

**UPD:** I just want to share my guess about why that `onErrorResume()` in `logIn()` didn't work. My tacit understanding is that such handlers handle exceptions thrown from the `Mono` they are chained to, `Mono<ServerResponse>` in that case. However, the exception is thrown from `Mono<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken>`. If you chain a handler directly to `flatMap(authenticationManager::authenticate)` and put a breakpoint there, the breakpoint is hit. On the other hand, the `WebFilter` solution relies on chaining `onErrorResume()` to `Mono<Void>` which is *also* not a `Mono<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken>`... Confusing